# Parse - Error when sending a boolean as PFObject (easy)

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, pfobject

I'm trying to send a object where one of the elements is a boolean. The error comes in line 5 and 7 where "isCheating" is a boolean and false is obviously one too.

My code looks like this:

```
@IBAction func sendTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    for receiver in recievers{

        var textMessage = PFObject(className:"textMessage")
        textMessage["Receiver"] = receiver
        textMessage["Cheating"] = isCheating
        textMessage["Message"] = textLabel.text
        textMessage["RevealID"] = false
        textMessage.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (success: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if (success != nil) {
                NSLog("Object created with id: \(textMessage.objectId)")
            } else {
                NSLog("%@", error)
            }
        }


    }

}
```

The error says: invalid type for key Cheating, expected string, but got boolean (Code: 111, Version: 1.6.1)

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

EDIT: I solved the issue, all I had to do was to drop the class in Parse, and the code worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

How about this one ?

```
textMessage["Cheating"] = "isCheating"
```

Comment: Issue solved, it's a bug on the server-side which forces you to drop the class if you're trying to add additional elements to your object.